# A better /about Question and Answer

Tags: discussion

Recently a new style [/about](https://serverfault.com/about) page has been provided for Server Fault. The expectation is that this will better explain how Stackexchange sites work. Unfortunately the example provided looks to be a shopping question with link only answers, which isn't a good thing.

Fortunately we can change the question providing the new one meets certain criteria.

- The question must come from this query http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/92078/possible-about-questions (if there isn't a suitable one in the first 200 then it can be extended)
- If there are more than two answers (I think) shorter answers will be preferred so as not to overwhelm the content of the page.

If you have a few minutes please [sift through the questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/92078/possible-about-questions)  and try to find a better Q&A to show off on the /about page then post it below.

Comment: Wow, someone really screwed the pooch there...

Comment: @ChrisS I think they just took the first Q&A that matched the query.

Comment: It's a nice enough page but it's just one more page newbies won't bother to read and the rest of us already know, or at least *should* know, how the site works.

Comment: Looking at the four answers below, and seeing that we've found at least one way to disqualify all of them... man, we're all going to die alone, aren't we.

Comment: Having had a brief look at the list of questions all I can say is that many of them are either very poor or downright off topic. That query could almost be used as a garbage detector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty lazy, so the second question from that query looks good enough to me:

- [Does adding more drives to a RAID 10 Array increase performance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392796)

It's certainly not the best question, but at least it's not explicitly off-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: There will be a tool provided RSN to allow Mods to change this.

Comment: The 2nd answer on that question is pretty piss poor though...

Comment: Yep, room for improvement... Just need someone to find a better option.

Comment: FYI: the current about page has the "unicorns and daisies" default question.

Comment: Wonderful... wonder when that got borked.

Answer (score 2):

I like this question:

[Grepping through .gz log files](https://serverfault.com/questions/268530/grepping-through-gz-log-files)

Highly technical, good question, and the top 3 answers are all very good

Comment: That's because the top three answers are effectively all the same, which makes it not a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to nominate the following questions:

- [Disable password complexity rule in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/q/19611/126632)
- <strike>[How to prevent normal users from shutting down the system?](https://serverfault.com/q/49224/126632)</strike>

Comment: The latter has pretty much a link only accepted answer which wouldn't be great.

Comment: Oh crap, you're right.

Comment: The first Question's Accepted Answer is pretty wordy. Either it wouldn't fit on the /About page, or it'd result in a word-wall.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

- [Industry Standards for Network Infrastructure Labeling](https://serverfault.com/questions/297283/industry-standards-for-network-infrastructure-labeling)

It's honestly the only good question with good answers that I could find that wasn't subjective, too broad or shopping.

Also - it covers a topic that superuser-audience-driveby's would NEVER ask about it.. :)

Comment: Too localised an example for a global site.